# jQuery returns []

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CASE**

jQuery retuns `[]` when there's no matched elements by given selectors.

---

**RESULT SUMMARY**

```
var a = $("");      // -> returns []
var b = $();        // -> returns []
var c = $(null);    // -> returns []
var d = $("#abcd"); // -> returns [] there's no elements that have 'abcd' id attribute.

// FYI : Below results go same with 'b', 'c', 'd' as well.
typeof a            // -> "object"
a instanceof jQuery // -> true
$.isEmptyObject(a)  // -> false
if ( a == null )    // -> false
if ( a == undefined)// -> false

// workaround to get to know 'a' is an empty, invalid jQuery object.
a.size()            // -> 0 ... as Pebb said, this has been deprecated from version 1.8
a.length()
a[0]                // -> undefined
```

---

**HOW CAN I MAKE A SAFEGUARD?**

As you can see above **RESULT SUMMARY**, There's no way to gurantee that it's a safe jquery object except the workaround I specified above. But `.size()` is for measuring how many objects the jquery object contains and `object[index]` is to get an ojbect or a value from `Array` or a plain object from `jQuery object`.

Well no one is going to blame me for using the workaround, but I feel like something is missing.

---

**UPDATE SCENERIO**

***I didn't mean to tell you that returing `[]` is not safe and something wrong with it***. I forgot to suggest you this kind of scenerio, it was my bad after all.

Let's say there's a user input and users type `id` values for something to happen on their browser. It can be done when we already know which `id` values users will type in. Code will look like below

```
// id variable is what user typed in a textbox
var target = $(id);

// Let's say we need the target's height, As Alfonso Garnett said this will return null
// Because there is no DOM elements to get its height value.
target.height();
```

So, we may need to validate the `target` is safe to use `height()` api or not. That's why returning `[]` doesn't seem to be safe under this kind of circumstance. That's what I'm asking.

---

**SECOND UPDATE**

Ok, `.height()`, even from an empty jquery object, will return null and no error. But after getting the height value, we can assume that there will be a calculating process.

```
var result = 12345 + target.height();
```

If `target.height()` returns `null`, then the result will be `12345` when the result must be `12345 + n`. If there's no error, can we easily find out where is the problem in the calculation processes? well, considering the rest of codes will run fine without any break, that is a pure advantage. But we will only get to know what is wrong with the calculations when we find out `target.height()` was giving us `null`.

No one, I guess, want this to happen. I just want to check if the jquery object is safe to use `jQuery APIs`, and want to make sure it will return some usable values for my program.

Comment: Why do you need your memory? Docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: What's there to safeguard? The fact that it returns an empty set _is_ the safeguard.

Comment: It doesn't return an array, it returns an empty jQuery collection. Returning `null` would be a terrible antipattern.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I think the problem is the OP is entering these in the console.  The console displays an empty jQuery object as `[]` leading the OP to think that it's an array; it's not, it's still an (empty) jQuery object.  For example, `$('.abcd') instanceof $` returns `true`.

Comment: Yeah, `[]` still has jQuery methods, and applying a method to an empty jQuery object throws no error, the method just returns the empty `[]` again.

Comment: Standardly you use `.length` to determine if a jQuery result set has contents. As stated in the docs: `If no elements match the provided selector, the new jQuery object is "empty"; that is, it contains no elements and has .length property of 0.` Also `.size()` has been deprecated. https://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: I don't get the update. `$('fgdfgfd').height()` throws no error either, just returns a null height. Even doing something like `$('body').height( $('gdfgdf').height() );` is of no consequence.

Comment: I might mess up my question, choosing some wrong words and not providing insufficient scenerios. I updated my answer again and give me some hands would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the principle that applies here is "garbage in, garbage out. " How could jQuery possibly return something more sensible than an empty jQuery object if you give it an input that doesn't select any elements?  The only possible rational behavior would be to throw an exception, but I think jQuery's choice is much more reasonable, because an empty selection is a valid possibility.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors *always* return a jQuery object; if it's empty, it's empty.  I think the problem here is that if you type these commands at the console, the (empty) jQuery objects that are returned are array-like, leading the console to display it like an array (`[]`).  It's not: it's still a jQuery object.  For example, try the following at the console:

```
$('.abcd') instanceof jQuery    // true
$('.abcd') instanceof $         // true
```

There's nothing to "safeguard" or protect here; jQuery is behaving perfectly consistently.

Since a jQuery object is always returned, you can invoke any jQuery method (such as `.height()`) successfully; no exception will be thrown.  It just so happens that `.height()` in this case will quite reasonably return `null`, because there was nothing matched to take the height of.  But no exception will be thrown.

Comment: ".toString() implementations that simply return the string []". No, jQuery object is an array-like object. Console shows the live representation of the object.

Comment: Good point, Vohuman, and you're correct.  I'm not 100% aware of the ins and outs of how the console renders thing.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: No I already knew that is a jquery object. I updated my answer. I think I made all of you guys confused here.